# Notation for "vectorized" function

Tags: notation

Is there a notation for expressing vectorization of a function as implemented by Mathematica's [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)

```
In[1] = Map[f,{a,b,c,d,e}]
Out[1] = {f[a],f[b],f[c],f[d],f[e]}
```

or Haskell's [`fmap`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=fmap)?

```
ghci> fmap (+10) [1,2,3] 
[11,12,13]
```

That is, given a function $x_i \mapsto f(x_i)$, is there a common typographic idiom of decorating or marking $f$ to express the function $g(\boldsymbol{x})\mapsto (g(x_0),g(x_1),\ldots,g(x_n))$, for $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$?

I've seen something like

$$\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x})$$

used occasionally; but it's not clear that this would be understood without having stated that $\boldsymbol{f}:=g$.

Comment: If you think in terms of sets, rather than lists, then the equivalent of `map f xs` is the **image** of a set $\mathcal X$ under a function $f$, i.e., $$f (\mathcal X) := \{ f (x) \mid x \in \mathcal X\}$$

Comment: If you care about the order, though, while I've never seen anyone introduce this concept without defining the notation, a sensible idea based on the above might be to simply write $f(\mathbf{x})$ and to explain what this means when you introduce it. The closest I've seen is in linear programming or optimization, where $\mathbf{x}-1 \geq 0$ is typically shorthand for the equivalent coordinate-wise statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you *could* do something like

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{f}_g(\boldsymbol{x}),
\end{equation}

but you would have to define it; it's not a notation I've seen before (nor can I remember to have ever needed it). (The definition of the above would be:

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{f}_g(\boldsymbol{x}) \equiv (g(x_1),\,g(x_2),\,\dots,(g(x_n)),
\end{equation}

).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just $\big( f(x_i) \big)_i$? But mentioned above, I think what you search for is usually written out or explained explicitly.