# Is it okay to say $\cos(a)$ where $a$ is a vector?

Tags: notation

Assume you have vectors $a$ and $b$. They are not precisely defined but in the text mentioned as vectors. Can I use the following notation to mean element-wise product of $a_k$ and $\cos(b_k)$?

$$\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
     a\cos b\\
     a\sin b\\
  \end{array}
\right)$$

which is also a vector. If it is not appropriate, would you suggest some options?

Comment: You have to define it. Then it is - of course - ok.

Comment: This is pretty unusual. You may use it if you explicitly introduce that notation. As far as I know, there is not even a notation for component-wise multiplies.

Comment: There are programming languages that already use that type of operations (Matlab, for instance). But it is not usual in mathematical notation, unless you previously define it, of course.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "component-wise multiplies" is often indicated as $\circ$ and is called the "Schur-Hadamard product".

Comment: Somewhat related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694281/notation-for-vectorized-function

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: then $a\circ\cos(b)$ or $a\circ\cos_\circ b$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust interesting idea with the cosine.  I've also seen $\cos[b]$ as a notation for entry-wise functions.

Comment: In math you can make definitions and build on them like it is nobody's business.....is it okey? As long as you define what you mean you are fine. As you do this over time your definition making skills get better....also, sometimes you will find people will most likely have defined the same thing a few decades/centuries ago under a different name.